# Rails - Update the values of the attributes of a result of a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, key-value-store

In my Rails application, I have **Student**, **Teacher** and **Course** model.

**teacher.rb**

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :students, through: :courses
end
```

**student.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :teachers, through: :courses
end
```

**course.rb**

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :students
  belongs_to :teachers
end
```

I'm joining the tables and display in a page.

```
result = Course.joins(:teacher)
                      .joins('left join students on students.id = courses.student_id')
                      .select("courses_name, teachers.name as teachers_name, students.name as student_name, students.source as student_source")
```

result.attributes will give the values in a Hash. I want every value in the attributes hash to be updated to some other value.
For ex,

```
result.attributes.transform_values{|v| ERB::Util.html_escape(v)}.
```

But this will not save in the result. I want the updated values to be stored in the **result** variable and don't have to store the updated values in the database.(should not call validations). Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You are selecting several attributes from those tables. Which attribute do you want to multiply by 10? I guess not the phone number...

Comment: Yes, not the phone number. It is just an example. But my question is I want to update all the values and not some specific value. Is there any method that will update all the values?

Comment: Updating a specific attribute would be easy, but I am not aware of any method that updates all attributes on an instance of ActiveRecord without naming the attribute. And honestly, I cannot think about a use case in which it makes sense to update all attributes of an object without naming them or at least checking the datatype first.

Comment: Basically, it is not just multiplication and is regardless of the data type. I just want to call a method for each that will decorate the value. Like html_escaping or json_escape or concatenation.

Comment: Your example is causing a lot of confusion. Maybe give a example of exactly what you want to do so we can better understand, rather than multiplying fields by 10. If you do update your example, change your question rather than clarifying down here in the comments.

Comment: Why do you want to HTML escape all attributes manually? Why don't you rely on Rails auto escaping values when rendered in a view?